# Does ServiceStack.RabbitMq support creating Quorum queues?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, servicestack, .net-6.0, high-availability

RabbitMQ allows for ['Quorum Queues'](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#feature-comparison). As far as I have read in the documentation, 'quorum' queues allow queues to be replicated on all nodes within a rabbit cluster, whereas 'classic' queues host a specific queue on a specific node. I understand that there will be a higher latency when using 'quorum' over 'classic' queues.

I use ServiceStack to talk to RabbitMQ. The exchanges and the queues are created automatically - based around my requests and responses, and this all works well.

I am writing software for use in a highly available environment - I am writing C# code, using .NET 6 in a Linux environment (docker containers running in K8s), and am using ServiceStack 6.0.2. I would like to use 'quorum' queues rather than 'classic' queues if possible to help prevent message loss if one of the rabbit nodes in the cluster goes down.

Is it possible for ServiceStack to create 'quorum' queues? Having read through the documentation, searched SO, searched the ServiceStack forums, general web searching and experimentation in a stand-alone application, I can find no obvious way of creating these types of queues automatically via ServiceStack. By the looks of it, the queues are registered with various features, but always seem to be created as 'classic' queues.

Furthermore, will there be any problem with using ServiceStack and 'quorum' queues? The [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#feature-comparison) suggests that `A client library that can use regular mirrored queues will be able to use quorum queues.`, but I am unclear if this is the case with ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ServiceStack doesn't support creating Rabbit MQ Quorum Queues.

[ServiceStack MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging) is a messaging abstraction over multiple MQ implementations to enable alternative Reply and OneWay endpoints for invoking your Services.

You'll need to utilize the MQ libraries directly when you need additional MQ-specific features beyond this.